# How can I add frames to a gif with NodeJS and gif-encoder-2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gif

So I'm trying to make an app that adds frames to a gif whenever it receives a post request with some image data.

```js
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("node:path");
const sizeOf = require("image-size");
const GIFEncoder = require("gif-encoder-2");
const { Image, createCanvas } = require("canvas");
const app = new express();
const port = 5000;

const timelapseFile = path.join(__dirname, "public", "timelapse.gif");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html");
});

app.post("/timelapse", function (req, res) {
  const { file } = req.files;
  if (!file) return res.sendStatus(400);

  const { width, height } = sizeOf(file.data);

  let encoder = new GIFEncoder(width, height, "octree");

  encoder.createReadStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(timelapseFile));

  encoder.start();
  encoder.setRepeat(0);
  encoder.setDelay(500);

  let img = new Image();
  img.src = file.data;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  encoder.addFrame(ctx);

  encoder.finish();

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port);
```

So far that's what I've done, but this creates a whole new gif with just one frame, the one it just received. Is it possible to add onto that already existing gif?